# Set/Force User-Agent for iFrame content

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, ionic-framework

Am trying to load a page in an iFrame and I would like to force some Mobile User Agent all the time. Be it a phone/Tablet/Handheld devices, I would like the iframe to load the page with that particular User-Agent

I tried using some JS methods like __defineGetter , so and so. None of them worked. Please help me out.

Comment: You could try using a proxy that changes the user agent.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fixed it by adding  in config.xml

Comment: Please provide more details in regarding how you had it fixed, what environment you are running your app on.